# Passing data from one SKScene to the next

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

So I am designing a game. In my `MenuScene` class I have the following:

`-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition fadeWithColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:147.0/255.0 green:213.0/255.0 blue:216.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] duration:2.0f];
    MyScene *gameScene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:self.size];
    [self.view presentScene:gameScene transition:transition];
}`

Which transitions to the game scene. I need to pass some data to the game scene. In the game scene, which is an instance of `MyScene`, I have

```
@interface MyScene()

@property (nonatomic) SKSpriteNode *heli;
@property (nonatomic) int health;
@property (nonatomic) float currentDY;
@property (nonatomic) float gameSpeed;



@end
```

And I want to be able to set these properties as I enter the new scene, based on input from the user from the old scene. In my research I have come to the conclusion that I will either want to use **initWithCoder** or some other sort of custom method to transition to the scene. Do I need to add a new method to my interface and then implement it in the implementation? How do I need to change my game scene to accept this new data? Do I need to replace `initWithSize` with my new method, let's say it is `initWithSize:andFuel:`?

Could someone please provide a simple example of how this would be done, in both the implementation and the interface?

Comment: This is a simple indicator that you need to do one or both of two things. Create a Subclass of SKScene that follows a custom protocol which is the ancestor of your SKScene subclasses, and move some amount of model properties / ivars to a global object like the app delegate. This is one reason the 8.0 and 10.10 SDK adds a scene delegate. It's a really common thing to do.

Comment: I am new to XCode and so I had trouble following your comment. I know how to create a subclass of SKScene... But not how to create a custom protocol or make it follow that custom protocol.. Or really anything after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally have found NSUserDefaults to be the simplest solution to this.

To use your example, you can store health, currentDY and game speed in a dictionary like so:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSDictionary *settingsDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:health], @"health",
                              [NSNumber numberWithFloat: currentDY], @"currentDY",
                              [NSNumber numberWithFloat: gameSpeed], @"gameSpeed",
                              nil];

[defaults setObject: settingsDict forKey:@"settingsDict"];

[defaults synchronize];
```

Keep in mind that you can only store objects in a dictionary and not primitives like int, float, etc... That is why you have to convert them into NSNumber.

To get get them back out during the init method, you do this:

```
NSDictionary *settingsDict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"settingsDict"];

int health = [[settingsDict objectForKey:@"health"] intValue];
float currentDY = [[settingsDict objectForKey:@"currentDY"] floatValue];
float gameSpeed = [[settingsDict objectForKey:@"gameSpeed"] floatValue];
```

I have never tried storing a SKSpriteNode in a dictionary and then storing it with NSUserDefaults. If it does not work, you will have to store all of the sprite's properties such as location, texture name, physics body specs, etc.. into a dictionary. You can then simply create a new sprite based on the stored values when you need it.

Comment: So, this will work everywhere? If I edit the user defaults in one class it will change them for the other classes? Do I need to add any import statements in my classes?

Comment: @user2391236 - You do not need any additional code to read/write with NSUserDefaults but I would suggest you read the class reference for it. Not sure what you mean by the class question.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out that I have solved my own question, but I will give credit to the answerer above because he presented another solution. My solution makes more sense to me, however.

All I did was:

In my game scene, I created a new method `initWithSize: fuel:` and called `if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {` the same way `initWithSize` does. **Then,** in my menu class, I replaced

```
MyScene *gameScene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:self.size];
```

With `MyScene *gameScene = [MyScene alloc];`

And then `gameScene = [gameScene initWithSize:self.frame.size fuel:1];`

I haven't had any issues with it so far - could someone tell me if I am doing anything incorrectly here? This seems to allow me to pass info into my next scene by creating a custom init method.

Comment: I've implemented a similar method for this problem. Would also like to know if there are any problems.