# how to pass data from skscene to app delegate

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am trying to save my highscore in a game. I want to pass the highscore variable from an skscene to the app delegate to save. Is there any way to do this.

I also want to know if there is a way to send the variable back to the skscene.

**Edit:**

At the time of the post I did not know that you can access a variable stored in NSUserDefaults from any scene in the app. I thought it had to be a file that all other files could access.

Now I know that any scene can access another scene and NSUserDefaults will work on any scene.

Comment: Why do you want to use the App Delegate to save your high score?

Comment: That is the way I found how to use NSUserDefaults. IS there a better way?

Comment: You can use NSUserDefaults from practically any place, including your scene.

Comment: I'm really not fully sure how to do it. Can you post an answer on how to do it from the scene then. I have found a lot of different ways and  they won't work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354504/passing-data-from-one-skscene-to-the-next/25354782#25354782

Comment: If you know how to use NSUserDefaults from AppDelegate you know how to use it from any other class. There is no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using NSUserDefaults, you can save any score you want as follows:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:highscore forKey:@"highscore"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Subsequently, you can fetch the value from anywhere within the app using:

```
NSInteger score = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"highscore"];
```

If needed, have a look at the NSUserDefaults [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).